# Ubuntu can't read repository

Tags: ubuntu, repository

I ran the command on Ubuntu 19.04

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                                                                        
Hit:3 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                     
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:5 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:6 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed InRelease                                                                                                                                        
Hit:7 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:8 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu vs-bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                    
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.04/prod disco InRelease                                                                                                         
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release                                                                                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                              
Get:13 https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs vscodium InRelease [2 400 B]
Reading package lists... Done             
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Why it shows error? I have the following repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                            OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS                             #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse 

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: You have more repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/816190

Answer (score 0):

[Bionic is for version 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/).
[Dingo is for version 19.04 which you are using](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/).
Substitute 'dingo' where you now have 'bionic'.

Answer (score 0):

> `Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release`
>   `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.`

You should keep `bionic`  codename instead of `disco` (it doesn't exist yet) , see the list of the accepted Ubuntu [codenames here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/).

Use the following command:

```
sudo sed -i 's/disco/bionic/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gezakovacs*.list
sudo apt update
```